# How to Query with multiple conditions on same field in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have this array:

```
cars = ["green", "blue", "red", "yellow"]
```

And I would like to conditionate with the same **name** field, for example:

```
Car.where(name: 'green', name: 'blue', name: 'red', name: 'yellow')
```

I am looking for a condition where I can bring all the cars with those four names

Is there a more practical way to simplify the multiple conditions query? So that it can be optimal

Comment: sorry I don't get what's the behaviour you want. which are the rows you want as a result?

Comment: I would like to make a query with those four values

Extract all cars with names: yellow, green, blue and red for example

Comment: so you want in return rows with name green or name blue or name red or name yellow right?

Comment: Exactly, that I return the collection whose name is: yellow, red, blue and green @Ursus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Car.where(name: ["green", "blue", "red", "yellow"])
```

this returns you a relation with rows of cars which have name green or blue or red or yellow. in SQL that translates to something like

```
SELECT cars.*
FROM cars
WHERE name IN ('green', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow')
```

note that this hash

```
{ name: 'green', name: 'blue', name: 'red', name: 'yellow' }
```

the one you passed to `where`, always evaluates to

```
{ name: 'yellow' }
```

because you can't instantiate an hash with a key present more than once. the last one is kept

Comment: Oh great!!, thank you very much for the explanation and also for including the hashes example :D It worked great for me

Comment: Ruby will/should actually warn you if you duplicate a key. In Ruby 3.0.2 it generate `warning: key :name is duplicated and overwritten`.